# Boundedness of Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I encountered the following problem but I have no idea how to proceed.. Basically, I have a class of periodic function satisfying certain properties, and since I do not have explicit form of them I use their Fourier expansions, and hope to arrive the minimum value of $g(x)+g(\alpha-x)$ over interval $x\in(0,\alpha]$, where $\alpha\in(0,\pi/2]$.

**Problem setting**

Consider a $2\pi$-periodic function $g(x)$, $x\in\mathbb{E}$. By Fourier theorem, it can be represented as
$$g(x)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin nx+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\cos nx$$

The odd function $g(x)$ $$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\sin nx$$
where $b_n=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(x)\sin nx\ dx,\forall n=1,2,\cdots$.
satisfying the following constraints

(1) $g(\pi/2)=1$

(2) $g'(x)>0,x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

(3) $g(x)$ is symmetric to $x=\pi/2$.

As an example, $g(x)=\sin x$ is one of candidates.

By direct plug-in, from (1) we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}=\pi$.

From (2) we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big\{\Big(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g'(x)\sin nx+ng(x)\cos nx\ dx\Big)\sin nx+ \frac{n}{\pi}\cos nx \Big(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(x)\sin nx\ dx\Big)\Big\}>0$

**My question**

Is it possible to obtain the lower bound of $\min_{x\in(0,\alpha]}g(x)+g(\alpha-x)>0$?

By direct plug-in, it is equivalent to
$\min_{x\in(0,\alpha]}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \big[\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(x)\sin nx\ dx\big]\big(\cos nx+\cos(n(\alpha-x))\big)>0
$

Swap $\min$ and $\sum$, we obtain
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \min_{x\in(0,\alpha]}\big[\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(x)\sin nx\ dx\big]\sin\frac{n\alpha}{2}\cos(nx-\frac{n\alpha}{2})>0
$

But then, how should I proceed with this? I feel this might be an ill-posed problem, so maybe should add more constraints on $g$ to make it well-posed?